# Blacklist only one specific version of a package for upgrades

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, held-packages

Let's say we have a package `mypackage` that is available in different versions from different sources. I do *not* want to disable any of these sources though.

However, the currently latest version of `mypackage` is buggy on my system, but previous versions ran fine and probably future versions will be fixed again as well.

How can I blacklist only this buggy version of `mypackage` so that `apt` does not upgrade to it, but continues receiving upgrades from all sources and will upgrade to the following versions once they are out?

Holding the package back (`apt-mark hold mypackage` would also prevent future updates until I manually unhold the package, which s *not* what I want.

Comment: Knowing my luck the next version would have the same glitch.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can put this in `/etc/apt/preferences` to assign priority < 100 to this particular version of the package:

```
Package: mypackage
Pin: version 1.2-3ubuntu4
Pin-Priority: 99
```

This will prevent the upgrade to this version, because the currently installed version is assigned priority 100 (and the package with the highest priority gets installed).

For more information, see `man apt_preferences` or [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170079/update-single-package-from-ubuntu-utopic-unicorn-when-running-trusty-tahr/170100#170100).

Comment: That seems exactly like what I was looking for. I hope I'll be able to test your solution tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that worked as intended. Sorry that I didn't have time to verify your answer earlier :)