# Ubuntu hangs after last update upgrade

Tags: updates

I recently installed **Ubuntu 20.04** LTS and update and upgrade it and just installed vlc.

after I reboot my PC and log in again everything is fine but it hangs if I go and click to open file manager or terminal or anything it will stuck and nothing works and some parts of my monitor start blinking then I cant just reset the system.
Is this problem from the last update?
how I can dis upgrade and back to the last version?
please help.

Comment: There have been several questions about this same problem posted at Ask Ubuntu today. From the recent update history it could be caused by either a kernel update or an Nvidia proprietary driver update. What happens when you select [Advanced options for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1014753/) in the grub boot menu and boot to an earlier kernel version?

Comment: my graphic card is intel Xeon onboard graphic. I don't have an Nvidia graphic. and about the driver, I even tried to boot ubuntu from grub and changed the mode to nomodeset.it's still the same.

Comment: yes i tried linux kernel 5.4.0-42-generic version and it works fast and smooth like before.thanks.

Comment: but what about the problem of kernel is it gonna work or I should change the kernel in advance option every time I want to boot ubuntu?

Comment: First check if it works with an older kernel. If it works with an older kernel I'll tell you what command to run so that you don't have to select that kernel every time you want to boot Ubuntu. Instead it will boot to that kernel every time automatically.

Comment: yes, please. it's about 1 hour I'm doing everything and it's fine. what command I should run to set the older kernel as default

Comment: Make a note of which kernel version that is causing the problem. Uninstall the kernel version that is causing the problem. Then prevent the older kernel version from upgrading again to it by following the instructions in the answers to [Blacklist only one specific version of a package for upgrades](https://askubuntu.com/q/835361/).

Answer (score 4):

There have been several questions about this same problem posted at Ask Ubuntu today. From the recent update history it could be caused by either a kernel update or an Nvidia proprietary graphics driver update. Your computer doesn't have an Nvidia graphics processor, so try booting with an earlier kernel version. Select [Advanced options for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1014753/) in the grub boot menu and boot with an earlier kernel version.

If this solves the problem then make it so that you don't have to select that older kernel version every time you want to boot Ubuntu. Make a note of which kernel version was causing the problem. Uninstall the kernel version that was causing the problem. Then prevent the older kernel version from upgrading to it again by following the instructions in the answers to [Blacklist only one specific version of a package for upgrades](https://askubuntu.com/q/835361/).

Alternatively there is already a new kernel in both `focal-proposed` and `groovy-proposed`.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that there is already a new kernel in both `focal-proposed` and `groovy-proposed`.

Answer (score 0):

If your hardware has a problem with your current kernel or you just want to use a lower kernel version remove the latest Linux kernel version (for example linux-image-5.4.0-91-generic).

```
sudo apt purge linux-image-5.4.0-91-generic linux-headers-5.4.0-91-generic linux-headers-5.4.0-91
```

For a GUI way of doing the same thing you can install Grub Customizer with `sudo apt install grub-customizer` in Ubuntu 20.04 and later. In Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 you can install Grub Customizer with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt update
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

In the *General settings* tab of Grub Customizer click the dropdown menu for **predefined**, which lists all the available kernels. Choose an older kernel and click *Save*.