# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS get stuck at logo screen

Tags: boot

*I am using Ubuntu from last month, but today I tried to boot it and it get stuck at the logo screen I also disabled fast startup and secure boot ,also I add nomodeset but nothing actually improved.*

Comment: There have been several questions about this same problem posted at Ask Ubuntu in the past few days. From the recent update history it could be caused by either a kernel update or an Nvidia proprietary driver update. What happens when you select [Advanced options for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1014753/) in the grub boot menu and boot to an earlier kernel version?

Comment: I thinks it's most probably due to driver update as there was a Nvidia driver update notification in Windows , so please tell what to do

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday's software update in Ubuntu 20.04 updated nvidia-driver-450 to nvidia-driver-460. Yesterday's software update also updated all of the Nvidia 450 series packages from 450 to 460. The following commands will install the recommended proprietary Nvidia graphics driver in Ubuntu 20.04.

1. Remove all the nvidia packages.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt-get remove '^nvidia'
   sudo apt autoremove
   ```
2. If you have added an Nvidia PPA to `/etc/apt/sources.list` remove that PPA by prefacing its line in sources.list with a `#` to comment it out. Run `sudo apt update` to refresh the list of available software.
3. Reboot with `sudo reboot`
4. Run the following commands to install the recommended proprietary Nvidia graphics driver.

   ```
   sudo ubuntu-drivers install
   sudo reboot
   ```

If automatically installing the recommended proprietary Nvidia graphics drivers doesn't work, try reverting them back to an earlier version like nvidia-driver-450 or nvidia-driver-435.

If the above 4 steps don't work, the other possibility is that the boot problem is caused by a kernel update in Ubuntu 20.04 that has generated several questions at Ask Ubuntu in recent days and is answered in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1306391/).

Comment: So, why is it happening, according to your solution it first uninstall the drivers then we install them again, what's has been changed now, and also do we have to do this again as new driver update comes. Isn't there any long term solution

Comment: The reason why it is happening is that something fundamental about the Nvidia drivers has been changed by yesterday's software update in Ubuntu 20.04 which updated nvidia-driver-450 to nvidia-driver-460. Yesterday's software update also updated all of the Nvidia 450 series packages from 450 to 460. If reinstalling the proprietary Nvidia graphics drivers doesn't work try reverting them back to an earlier version