# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck on empty purple screen on boot

Tags: boot, nvidia

I know this question has been asked before but the suggested solutions I found on the web did not work for me. I am trying to boot into my ubuntu partition and it is getting stuck on the purple screen before the logo shows up.

I believe I might have updated some nvidia drivers before this problem began (software updater gave me a big list and I just pressed install).

Editing grub and changing quiet splash to noapic noacpi nosplash irqpoll the boot got stuck on [OK] started Daemon for power management.

Booting from an older kernel (5.4.0-72-generic) let me log in but the resolution was locked to 1024x768 and the graphics were generally really bad so I assume the graphics card was not being used.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what other steps I can take to debug/fix this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove all the nvidia packages and reboot.

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt-get remove '^nvidia'  
sudo apt autoremove  
sudo reboot
```

After rebooting Ubuntu will be using the built-in Nouveau open source graphics driver instead of the proprietary Nvidia graphics drivers.

If this doesn't work, the other possibility is that the boot problem is caused by a kernel update that is answered in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1306391/).

Comment: Thank you! Uninstalling the drivers worked, but it looks like transitions are not "animated" anymore and I am not sure cuda will work without these drivers, is there a safe way to reinstall nvidia drivers?

Comment: One safe way is to automatically install the *recommended* Nvidia proprietary graphics drivers with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall && sudo reboot`. This command will automatically install all the required Nvidia proprietary graphics drivers together in one command. Otherwise wait for the next relevant software update and try again.

Comment: I have tried installing the recommended drivers that way (and also installing nvidia-drivers-465, which was the recommended one) but both resulted in a stuck purple screen on boot. The graphics card works fine in WIndows but it is not being used in Ubuntu, any suggestions on how to get the drivers to play nice? Thank you!