# Blacklist specific version of package

Tags: apt, package-management, blacklist, pinning

I've just upgraded to a version of Ubuntu that's forcing a Snap of Firefox on me. This doesn't work for me, I don't want it. I've found an alterative source for the package (mozillateam's PPA still builds) but it's being trumped by the newer epoch of `1:1snap1-0ubuntu2`.

I want Apt to blacklist versions of the `firefox` package that contain `snap`.

There [is another question that features a lot of the same words](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835361/blacklist-only-one-specific-version-of-a-package-for-upgrades), but I don't see how its answer applies. That only seems to block one version. I assume there will be future `1:*snap*` versions, and I don't want to play ping-pong with this.

---

Dupe question helps. Added this to: `/etc/apt/preferences.d/99-kill-firefox-snap`.

```
Package: firefox
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 100
```

Thanks all.

Comment: SInce apt_preferences supports wildcards, that answer should work with very little change in essence. `Pin: version 1:*snap*` should work just fine. (With `Priority: -1` if you want absolutely block the matching package versions from installation)

Comment: You can use something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1206502/124466) to increase the priority of firefox from launchpad or decrease the priority of firefox from `*.ubuntu.com`. Instead of blacklisting the version, blacklist the origin

Comment: I VTC'd for https://askubuntu.com/questions/293619/assign-higher-priority-to-ppa since it has examples covering wildcards, origins and actual blocking by setting negative priority as well. The manpage says  regex is also supported, so `Pin: version /.*snap.*/` is also an option.

Comment: With the release origin marking, I can just select `Pin: release o=Ubuntu` for firefox and that covers it. Now it'll look anywhere else (eg PPA) before looking at Ubuntu's repos. Added an edit for Firefox users in the same situation.